# Is this one-to-many or many-to-many?

Tags: database

Having trouble figuring out relations in this scenario:

I want to create a checkbox list for income types. The UI will present as "What types of income do you receive?". The choices, to keep things simple, could be full-time, part-time and retirement.

Part of me thinks this is a one-to-many relation, and thereby won't necessitate an association table because one individual can have one or more income types. However, taking things literally, "full-time" employment can relate to many individuals. In this case, I won't be showing a summary table of how many of the individuals are "full-time", I am just dealing with one person and determining what their employment status is.

But I don't think of "full-time" as an entity, like, for example, actors and movies - where many actors can be in many movies and many movies can have many different actors.

I guess what's tripping me up is that a user can select more than one option, as opposed to a radio-button list or drop down list.

In this case, which is it?

Comment: It's definitely a many to many.
Anyway, if you don't want an association table, you can use a bitmask, but at this point you're not DB-oriented anymore!

Comment: @Teejay, care to elaborate in an answer?

Comment: FYI: not adverse to using an association table - just want to do it correctly.

Comment: Mhhh, I was writing an answer, but maybe I'm not understanding your question. You wrote *"and thereby won't necessitate an association table because one individual can have one or more income types"*... Do you want to write *can* or *can't*? IMHO, a individual CAN have two (or more) types of income.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you have the income type as a separate table or whether it is just a string.

For separate table it is many-to-many: Each person has multiple income types. Each income type has multiple persons.

Answer (score 1):

`many-to-many`: `Person` to `Employment Type`.

Many `Person`s may share a single `Employment Type`.

A single `Person` may have several `Employment Type`s.

Having said that, I've no idea how rich is your business model, but I'd attach `Employment Type` to an entity called `Employment` that would refer `Employment Type` by a `many-to-one` association (rather than referring it straight from `Person`).

Comment: Ok, that clarifies a bit - i will use an association table.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view this is a many-to-many relationship.

**Full-Time** is an entity (suppose a `INCOME_TYPES` table), exactly like an actor or a movie.

Since you tell us, you won't showing the things *income-type-side* but only *individual-side*, there are two alternatives:

1. De-normalize your schema and put 3-fields in the `INDIVIDUALS` table. This is not very nice.
2. If you do some of the things code-side, you can use a bitmask.

   - for example, 1 is for Full-time, 2 is for Part-Time and 4 is for retirement.